# Understanding Async in node js using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, methods, bluebird

I am trying to understand the following problem:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.promisifyAll(fs);

fs.readFileAsync('read.js','utf8').then(function(content) {
  console.log(content);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I understood that since I am promisifying **fs library** I can use `readFileAsync` as promise. But if i change the name of `readFileAsync` to `readFileAs` I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\nniranja\Venkat\promises_github.js:17
fs.readFileA("read.js",'utf8').then(function(content)
   ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nniranja\Venkat\promises_github.js:17:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Please help me to understand the significance of Async. Thank you.

Comment: There simply is no method with the name `readFileA`! I mean, what would you expect `fs.niranjan()` to do? It's exactly the same.

Comment: `But if i change the name of readFileAsync to readFileAs` - Are you reassigning or something?

Comment: @thefourtheye:Im just changing the method name readFileAsync to readFileAs/readFileA and executing the code again.

Comment: @NiranjanUpadhya Can you show the actual complete code you tried?

Comment: var fs=require('fs');
var Promise=require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);
fs.readFileA("read.js",'utf8').then(function(content)
  {
 console.log(content);
  }).catch(function(error)
  {
   console.log(error);
  })

Answer (score 1):

`readFileAs` is not a function in the fs module, nor is it a property that bluebird would add to the module.  So, it is expected that there is no `readFileAs` function found.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), `readFileAs` ain't a supported function so it ain't an asynchronous issue.

Answer (score 0):

Normal node calls come in pairs like

- `readFile`
- `readFileSync`

The Bluebird library defines functions such as `readFileAsync` when you `promisify` a library, so those are the ones you want to call.

@AndrewEisenberg is correct, and it looks like your keyboard is keeping letters from appearing as you have `readFileAsync`, `readFileAs`, and `readFileA` in your question.

Pay close attention to what you're typing in coding - every character counts!

Answer (score 0):

The method `readFileAs` you are trying to use doesn't exist on the [fs library](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) that's why you see that error.

The only ones that exist for purposes of reading files are:

- `read`
- `readSync`
- `readFile`
- `readFileSync`

---

According to [bluebird documentation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification), 
after you call `Promise.promisifyAll(fs);` you may use **fs's** methods exactly as they are documented, except by appending the `Async`-suffix to method calls and using the promise interface instead of the callback interface.

So following the API documentation you only append the `Async`-suffix to methods that exists on the fs library like the ones listed above.

Comment: :I dint know that bluebird adds Async keyword,Thanks.Can you please suggest me some links for understanding bluebird promises.

Comment: bluebird documentation is great, look at this [part](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) the explanation of promisification.